# Stack too deep error when trying to calculate two charity fees

Tags: solidity

How can I fix the below functions? I'm getting

```
CompilerError: Stack too deep, try removing local variables.
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee) = _getRValues(tAmount, tFee, tLiquidity, tCharity, tCharity2, _getRate());
```

Code:

```
function _getValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
    (uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity, uint256 tCharity, uint256 tCharity2) = _getTValues(tAmount);
    (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee) = _getRValues(tAmount, tFee, tLiquidity, tCharity, tCharity2, _getRate());
    return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee, tTransferAmount, tFee, tLiquidity, tCharity, tCharity2);
}

function _getTValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
    uint256 tFee = calculateTaxFee(tAmount);
    uint256 tLiquidity = calculateLiquidityFee(tAmount);
    uint256 tCharity = calculateCharityFee(tAmount);
    uint256 tCharity2 = calculateCharityFee(tAmount);
    uint256 tTransferAmount = tAmount.sub(tFee).sub(tLiquidity).sub(tCharity).sub(tCharity2);
    return (tTransferAmount, tFee, tLiquidity, tCharity, tCharity2);
}

function _getRValues(uint256 tAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity, uint256 tCharity, uint256 tCharity2, uint256 currentRate) private pure returns (uint256, uint256, uint256) {
    uint256 rAmount = tAmount.mul(currentRate);
    uint256 rFee = tFee.mul(currentRate);
    uint256 rLiquidity = tLiquidity.mul(currentRate);
    uint256 rCharity = tCharity.mul(currentRate);
    uint256 rCharity2 = tCharity2.mul(currentRate);
    uint256 rTransferAmount = rAmount.sub(rFee).sub(rLiquidity).sub(rCharity).sub(rCharity2);
    return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee);
}
```

Comment: so there are too many local variables ... 16 as I understand ... in `_getValues` ?

Comment: Yes. There are lots of suggested solutions in that other thread. Check it out.

Comment: I ended up adding some arrays that hold multiple values. Error gone :)